# PHP application deployment with elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, deployment, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a Laravel 5.1 PHP application that uses composer as PHP dependency manager and npm as JavaScript dependency manger, so far so good.

I want to have a live version of this application and I want automatic deployment with ElasticBeanstalk, I've created a confi file that looks like the following:

```
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_build.sh:
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    content: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        set -xe
        . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
        EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config  container -k app_staging_dir)
        cd $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR
        php artisan migrate --env="local"
        yum -y --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm
        npm install -g gulp
        npm install 
        gulp --production 

    option_settings:
      -
        namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command"
        option_name: Timeout
        value: 1600
```

this set sometime works and sometime it will take more than 30 mins to complete and 
elasticbeanstalk triggers a timeout error

Now  the reason the following block is there

```
yum -y --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm
npm install -g gulp
```

is because if the app needs to scale to multiple servers node can potentially
be not installed and that will install node for me

Now my question is: Am I doing it right? Is that the correct way to tackle automatic deployment?
sometime the deployment will take more than 30 minutes to execute, is it normal? can I improve my deployment?
I very like to type "eb deploy" and everything will go live!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the environment configuration options for this rather than writing a bash file yourself:

[Customising software on linux servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages)

This will allow you do something like this:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    nodejs: [] 
    npm: []
```

However:

> Elastic Beanstalk currently supports the following package managers: yum, rubygems, python, and rpm

So you'll still need to do the `npm install gulp`, ... manually